# Tcl Regular expression not working at the end of line

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to match a file that looks like this:

```
22.000 abc_/dasdf
23.652 abc_1/dasdf_0/l
```

The regular expression I used is this:

```
[regexp { (\S+)\s+(.+) } $line -> number name }
```

However, it only matches when there is a space after the string in the file. For example, it returns a match when:

```
22.000 abc_/dasdf<space>
```

But no match when there is nothing after `/dasdf`. By default, there are no such spaces after the string inside the file. Any reason why this could be?

Comment: You could also use `lassign [split $line] number name` (or `set name [lassign [split $line] number]` if the name can have space characters). It's about three times faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have spaces inside the braces. Those are significant.

Use

```
regexp {(\S+)\s+(.+)} $line -> number name
# ......^...........^ no spaces here
```

or if you want whitespace for readability:

```
regexp -expanded  { (\S+) \s+ (.+) } $line -> number name
```

Comment: Can also use `(?x)` _at the exact start of the RE_ to enable that flag. Sometimes it is easier to put the flags in the RE, sometimes not…